# I want to get next month record that starts from 1st date of month

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter. I want to get next month record. Suppose today is 19/10/2015, so I want record from 01/11/2015 to 30/11/2015.

I put this query but it shows from current date to 30 days. So , what could be the query for that? Any suggestion?

```
function get_next_month_birthday()
    {
        $this->db->select('fullname as name,avatar,birth_date,user_id',FALSE);
        $this->db->from('fx_account_details',FALSE);
        $this->db->where('birth_date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)');

        return $this->db->get()->result();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->db->where('month(birth_date) = month(date_add(last_day(curdate()), interval 1 day)');
```